# Python encoding japanese characters

Tags: python, encoding, cjk

I'm using python for code send request to server(crawl data).
But parameter is japanese. I'm using 
`str.encode(encoding='utf-8')` for parameter sent, method post

code request:
 `response = requests.request(self.method, self.url,data=self.param.encode(encoding='Shift_JIS'), headers=headers)`

but it's result is wrong base on info network of developer tool.

Example:
right values:

```
In: 千代田区     Out:%90%E7%91%E3%93c%8B%E6

In: 東京都       Out: %93%8C%8B%9E%93s
```

If I use utf-8(wrong value):

```
In:東京都        Out: \x93\x8c\x8b\x9e\x93s
```

Can you please help me in this case!

Thanks all!

Comment: Did you try URL-encoding, since you're trying to put it in a URL?

Comment: No, I;m using method post. I have updated question!

Comment: Its not the wrong value. Python shows the value in bytes '\x93\x8c\x8b\x9e\x93s' for '%93%8C%8B%9E%93s'. If you do `str.decode('utf-8')`, you will get the same character back.

Comment: Thanks @user8212173. it right, but i changed to Shift_JIS.

Answer (score 3):

```
import urllib
value = { 'my_jap_stuff' : '千代田区' }
urllib.urlencode(value)
```

or python 3 <

```
import urllib.parse
value = { 'my_jap_stuff' : '千代田区' }
urllib.parse.urlencode(value)
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if its the correct one @VuVuong. Cheers.

Comment: Your answer is good ideal, but I can not apply your code. Inside, try encode by str.encode of python with unicode : CP932 so easy to use

Comment: A nice way to do it @Chathuranga